# Single word for a grid pattern

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a single adjective/noun I could use to describe a grid pattern? Something that could be used in the place of "checkered", "plaid", or "pinstriped", but describing an empty lattice.

I'm looking for something that could be used in the sentence:

> "He had a ______ (hat/shirt/etc)"

Comment: There are many grid patterns. Can you include a picture in your question?

Comment: "Waffle knit" is a textile with an empty lattice appearance as well. Is this categorically a print pattern liked "checked" or pattern from the manufacturing technique like "pinstripe"?

Comment: From @WS2's deleted low-quality answer, but worth considering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gingham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Checked** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/checked)

> *adjective* Having a pattern of small squares
>
> *"a checked shirt"*
> *"In addition to checked patterns, stripes are also making waves this season."*

Answer (score 0):

[**tartan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartan) - usually reserved for kilts/skirts.

> Tartan is a pattern consisting of criss-crossed horizontal and
>   vertical bands in multiple colours. Tartans originated in woven wool,
>   but now they are made in many other materials. Tartan is particularly
>   associated with Scotland. Scottish kilts almost always have tartan
>   patterns. Tartan is often called plaid in North America, but in
>   Scotland, a plaid is a tartan cloth slung over the shoulder as a kilt
>   accessory, or a plain ordinary blanket such as one would have on a
>   bed.

**plaid** - a synonym for tartan in the US

**checked**

**checkered** - I think this is US-specific, not so much in the UK anyway.

**check** - contracted version of "checked" or "checkered", eg "check shirt".

Comment: Hi, Max. Your question was flagged as low-quality and I am not sure what went wrong. But I tried to edit your post. Take a look and see if it is OK. If you don't like it, you can roll it back. I think your post answers the question +1)

Comment: Thanks @Rathony - i think the flag was because it's seen as better practise to have the name be a link, and reproduce the definition afterwards (as you've done) than to just put a link in (which I did originally).

Comment: I am not so sure. But it is always better to make a hyper link. You can try [name or phrase](web address) to make a hyperlink. One possible reason I can think of is you just listed them without much detail.  Just my guess. :-)

Comment: Possible explanation for the flag: [Does a weak question legitimize a weak answer?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/8092/50044)

Comment: [Tartan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tartans) is a *specific style* of grid pattern - not a generic description for one. Q. asks for something "describing an empty lattice": *Tartan* cannot describe that.